# Integration of complicated hyperbolic functions

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, hyperbolic-functions

I have a complicated integral as below. I'd be appreciated if anyone could help me to find the answer.
$$
I=\int_{0}^{U}du [(\partial_uq)^2+w^2q^2]
$$
and the $q(u)$ is defined as 
$$
q(u)=Acoshwu+\frac{(B-AcoshwU)}{sinhwU}sinhwu
$$
Please note that "U" is a parameter which is totally constant in integral wrt 'u'.

I think the integration is simple but the partial derivatives and the square of the root makes it complicated especially for a student who distracted easily.

ANSWER: 
$$
I=w\frac{(A^2+B^2)coshwU-2AB}{2sinhwU}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function $q$ satisfies
$$
-q''(u)+w^2 q(u)=0,
$$
it is a good idea to integrate by parts. Doing so, you will find that
$$
\begin{split}
I&=\int_0^U \bigl[q'(u)^2+w^2q(u)^2\bigr]\,du\\
&=\Bigl[q(u)q'(u)\Bigr]_0^U+\int_0^U q(u)\bigl[-q''(u)+w^2 q(u)\bigr]\,du\\
&=q(U)q'(U)-q(0)q'(0).
\end{split}
$$
I'm sure you can differentiate $q$ and insert these limits.

Comment: this is really an impressive method. Thanks.